# Why oldIndex and newIndex always return 0 for Sortable JS (rubaxa-sortable)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jquery-ui-sortable, rubaxa-sortable

I am using sortable js for drag and drop action. ([Link to github page](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable)) As I am using vue.js as well, I am using [this plugin](https://github.com/David-Desmaisons/Vue.Dragable.For) to bridge them. I am new to both of the library and so I am trying to duplicate the example given in the plugin. (i.e. [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/dede89/u5ecgtsj/))

HTML section:

```
<div class="drag">
    <h2>List 1 v-dragable-for</h2>
    <div class="dragArea" >
        <template v-dragable-for="element in list1" options='{"group":{ "name":"people", "pull":"clone", "put":false }}' track-by="$index">
            <p>{{element.name}}</p>
        </template>
    </div>

    <h2>List 2 v-dragable-for</h2>
    <div class="dragArea">
        <div v-dragable-for="element in list2" options='{"group":"people"}' track-by="$index">{{element.name}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript part:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#main",
    data: {
        list1:[{name:"John" , id:"1"}, 
                {name:"Joao", id:"2"}, 
                {name:"Jean", id:"3"} ],
        list2:[{name:"Juan", id:"4"}, 
                {name:"Edgard", id:"5"}, 
                {name:"Johnson", id:"6"} ]
        },
    methods:{
        }
    });
```

It works fine on jsfiddle, but when I try to duplicate the case on my local server, it always return 0 for both oldIndex and newIndex in the onUpdate event. This makes the element always insert at the beginning of the second list. Any clue on what can I miss to cause this problem?

Comment: The problem *has* to be in the different javascript that your local server generates.

Comment: You should work in order to crate a jsfiddle that reproduce this problem so that it canbe investigated.

Comment: @DavidDesmaisons I tried my best to reproduce the problem, but I really have no idea. There is no error message, completely no clue on what makes the problem.... I will raise a bounty later if there are still no answer.

Comment: @cytsunny - I know this is late, but this is generally from not having defined the `draggable` property in the options for `Sortable.create`.